# How do I get the full call stack for await function in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node v12.8

Inside main() the program fails because error is thrown. However stack does not have main() or line number in it. How to determine line of failure?

```
async function p() {
 try {
  await main()
  } catch(e) {
    console.log( e.stack )
  }
}
setTimeout( p, 1000 )
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/async_hooks.html#async_hooks_promise_execution_tracking

Comment: Please post the stack (whatever is being logged)